# Generate a schema from .dll file using XSD generates error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

So I am using `Visual Studio 2005` for this. I need to generate a schema from a .dll file which used to work in the past, but now when doing:

```
xsd CustomDll.dll /type: CustomClass
```

I always get the annoying error:

```
Error: There was an error processing 'CustomDll.dll'  
- Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

I tried searching the internet, but none of the things I found helped me.

I don't even know exactly what for what issue to search for ? What are the possible causes for this ? Is there a way to retrieve `LoaderExceptions` property in `VS2005` ?

Any answer will be helpfull.

edit:

I used Fusion Logs, and this is what I get from one of the log files (the rest are all successful) :

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (10/1/2015 @ 5:30:56 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\bin\xsd.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

LOG: Start binding of native image xsd, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
LOG: IL assembly loaded from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\bin\xsd.exe.
WRN: No matching native image found.
LOG: Bind to native image assembly did not succeed. Use IL image.
```

Any idea what this means ?

Comment: It's likely a problem with dependencies of `CustomDll.dll`. You could get more information about that if you enable Fusion logging.

Comment: How can I enable Fusion logging ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But I really don't know what the log is really saying. I edited my question with the log.